# How to read files in directory in Javascript

Tags: javascript, directory, xmlhttprequest

I have to read files names for now from given directory as URL 
for example.

http://somesite.whereisthis/directoryThatContainsFiles

I thought about XMLHttpRequest like

```
xhr.open('GET', 'http://somesite.whereisthis/directoryThatContainsFiles', true);
```

and then somehow read names of files that are in this folder but I can't make it work :/

How to read them in pure javascript?(no jquery or something else) is there any way to list it in console.log();?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to return a list of all the image file names from a folder using only Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6994212/is-there-a-way-to-return-a-list-of-all-the-image-file-names-from-a-folder-using)

Answer (score 0):

**You Expecting a lot from "Javascript"**

Well you can't do it without server side help. For example you can use PHP to  send directory listing data as JSON response.

http://hostaddress/endpointdirectory

```
  {
      "Folder" : "Data"
      "Files"  : [ "File1" , "File2" ]
  }
```

Else there is work around simple hack using XMLHttpRequest() you will get HTML DOM response.

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Index of /directoryWantToList</title>
 </head>
  <body>
 <h1>Index of /directoryWantToList</h1>
 <table>
 <tr><th valign="top"><img src="/icons/blank.gif" alt="[ICO]"></th><th><a 
  href="?C=N;O=D">Name</a></th><th><a href="?C=M;O=A">Last modified</a></th>
  <th><a href="?C=S;O=A">Size</a></th><th><a href="?C=D;O=A">Description</a>
  </th></tr>
  <tr><th colspan="5"><hr></th></tr>
  <tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/back.gif" alt="[PARENTDIR]"></td>
  <td><a href="/">Parent Directory</a>       </td><td>&nbsp;</td><td 
   align="right">  - </td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
  <tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/text.gif" alt="[TXT]"></td><td><a 
  href="File1.txt">File1.txt</a>              </td><td align="right">2018-
  01-15 16:52  </td><td align="right">  0 </td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
  <tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/text.gif" alt="[TXT]"></td><td><a 
  href="File2.txt">File2.txt</a>              </td><td align="right">2018-
  01-15 16:52  </td><td align="right">  0 </td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
  <tr><th colspan="5"><hr></th></tr>
  </table>
  <address>Apache/2.4.29 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.0g PHP/7.2.0 Server at 
  localhost Port 80</address>
  </body></html>
```

Using this DOM Response you need to get those Files names by parsing elements which is a bad hack.....

Javascript evolving a lot today but still its limited to client side.

Reference Thread  :

1. [Listing files of a directory in a webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27860507/listing-files-of-a-directory-in-a-webpage)
2. [get a list of all folders in directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15537424/get-a-list-of-all-folders-in-directory)