# How to show all visited pages in a directory

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I would like to know how I could show which pages a user has visited in a website directory so they can jump back into projects. With JS and HTML.

For example if they visited https://mywebsite.com/docs/doc1

It will show that link and then if they visited doc3 it would also show up.

If I need to clarify let me know!

Basically I need to display all the links they visited in the docs directory with javascript

Comment: I think you can find your solution from the post . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010158/is-it-possible-to-get-a-list-of-files-under-a-directory-of-a-website-how

Comment: Is this restricted to just the docs folder? What if there's a query parameter? What if there's a URL fragment? What should be considered valid and what should be considered unique? Do you just want to maintain a list, indiscriminately, of every address visited at that domain? I think the question needs quite a bit of clarification.

Comment: @jsejcksn it does use params so it would be /docs?id=abc as it assigns a random id to each doc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using the looking through the browser history [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API)

This is the only option I know, else you need to create a browser plugin to do the tracking then on your site-directory talk with your extension.

Comment: Sorry I just clarified above @dean van greunen